# Cannot configure hibernate EntityManager configuration with .xml file

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data, nhibernate-mapping

I tried to write some code with EntityManager but hibernate was updated to hibernate-core(6.0.0.Final) and with new hibernate 6.0 my old codes doesn't work

There my code:
my pom.xml
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bUbEo.png)

my persistence.xml file

```
<persistence xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence
         http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd"
         version="2.1">

<persistence-unit name="CRM">

    <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>

    <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>

    <properties>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="org.postgresql.Driver"/>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5678/postgres"/>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="postgres"/>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="postgres"/>
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create"/>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect"/>
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

and my main method

```
        EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory =
            Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("CRM");

    EntityManager entityManager = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();

    entityManager.getTransaction().begin();

    entityManager.persist(new SuperHero());

    entityManager.getTransaction().commit();

    entityManager.close();

    entityManagerFactory.close();
```

here result

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l7UlG.png)

> thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks as if you are mixing 2 incompatible versions of Hibernate resources:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
    <version>6.0.0.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

and:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
    <version>5.6.7.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

From v6 onwards, the Hibernate libraries have moved from using Java Persistence to Jakarta Persistence. You can read about this larger Java ecosystem change elsewhere [Transition from Java EE to Jakarta EE](https://blogs.oracle.com/javamagazine/post/transition-from-java-ee-to-jakarta-ee) - and also in other SO questions and answers.

By including a Hibernate Entity Manager v5 dependency, your project will still be referring to a Java Persistence library (e.g. via `javax.persistence-api-2.2.jar` or similar). This means your code may still compile - but, as you see, it will not execute. You will see error messages referring to `javax` classes, which are no longer supported by the v6 Hibernate Core library.

Furthermore, Hibernate's JPA support has been merged into the hibernate-core module, making the hibernate-entitymanager module obsolete. You can see a note about this by looking at the readme.txt file in your Entity Manager 5.6.7 JAR file:

> *Hibernate's JPA support has been merged into the hibernate-core module, making this hibernate-entitymanager module obsolete.  This module will be removed in Hibernate ORM 6.0.*

**Recommended steps:**

1. Remove the `hibernate-entitymanager` dependency from your POM. That will probably trigger a series of compilation errors, because you will no longer have any library support for classes such as `javax.persistence.EntityManager`.
2. Update all your `javax` imports to `jakarta` imports. So, for example, taking the class from (1) above, that becomes:

```java
import jakarta.persistence.EntityManager;
```

3. In your `persistence.xml` file you will also need to fix any similar references to `javax` - for example:

```xml
<property name="jakarta.persistence.jdbc.driver" 
          value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
```

**Final Notes**

If you still face issues following the above steps, then you can refer to the official Hibernate ORM [6.0 Migration Guide](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/main/migration-guide.adoc).